# Why is kubectl not asking for a password?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Why is kubectl not asking for a password?

- I have created a kubernetes cluster on my server with kubeadm
- than I installed kubectl on my local machine
- and copied the content of /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf from my server into the file ~/.kube/config on my local machine.

Now I cann access my own cluster from my local machine with kubectl without the need of a passphrase? Why is this so?

When I want ot access my server via ssh I need of course a user/password or an allowed ssh key. Why does kubectl not ask me for a passphrase?
To me it seems not to be secure enoght.

Comment: You know - you can access you server using ssh key with no entering password, right?

Comment: Yes, only in case my ssh private key has no password - right?

Comment: This is "[other](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication)" type of authentication. In simple words, the algorithm allows to public/nonsecret key to verify the identity of secret/private key owner using math operations.

Comment: but to copy the kubernetes/admin.conf on my workstation is like to copy the root password from my server into my local file system. This is what I did not understand.

Comment: So leave it on your server and command your k8s cluster from there. On other points, an account in your kubeconfig can have a different set of privileges (not a root one) or work in a webhook mode (but that a different topic)

Comment: understood - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes supports different authentication strategies, defined [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

Generally, Kubernetes cluster uses `client certificate authentication`. If you look at your `~/.kube/config` file you'll see a field something like this:

```
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: <BASE64 ENCODED X509 CERTIFICATE>
    client-key-data:  <BASE64 ENCODED PRIVATE KEY FOR THE CERTIFICATE>
```

You can see that the `kubernetes-admin` user has a client certificate data and key. This certificate is trusted by the `Certificate Authority (CA)` of your cluster.

When you use `kubectl`, it sends the `client certificate data` of the user to your cluster and your cluster `CA` verifies it. If the client is verified, then you can access the cluster.

Comment: Client certs are an option but definitely not the most common, OIDC is the most common auth option by far. Client certs for kubectl are generally not a good idea because there is no revocation model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it now better but it seems to be not so easy to manage access. I found this [blog](https://medium.com/better-programming/k8s-tips-give-access-to-your-clusterwith-a-client-certificate-dfb3b71a76fe) how to create client certificates.  But it is not an easy way. I thought I can provide my public ssh key anywhere in the kubernetes master node to use the api server with my private key.